# Ands and Commas

Tags: punctuation, relative-clauses

I'm trying to construct a relative clause that's deliberately crammed with a lot of info. This is to illustrate to someone the flexibility of relative clauses (versus adjectives).

Here's my independent clause: *I met a girl...*

Now, I need to make a relative clause that starts with "who" and contains every one of the following details:

1. beautiful
2. smart
3. tall
4. has big, brown eyes
5. has long, black hair

Now my question is: how many *ands* do I use? Also, at which points do I place the commas?

This is what I came up with on my own:

> I met a girl who is beautiful, smart and tall, and has big, brown
>   eyes and long, black hair.

Should there be an "*and*" before "*has*"? In fact, are all my "*ands*" and commas placed correctly? I would like to avoid making two separate sentences.

---

P.S. I hope this particular example doesn't sound sexist to anybody.

Comment: Delete the first "and". The commas are fine.

Comment: In many instances, it is a matter of style. The rhetorical device of using many conjunctions in close succession is called [polysyndeton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysyndeton).

Comment: I like the 'and' between smart and tall, but would change to 'with' instead of 'and has'. I would also remove the commas after big and long:  '*I met a girl who is beautiful, smart and tall, with big brown eyes and long black hair.*'

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with the _smart_ coming between two 'appearance' adjectives, and for the same reason prefer Jim's choice of _with_. I'd rewrite thus: I met a girl who is beautiful (with big brown eyes and long black hair), tall - _and_ smart. Sadly, this rewrite doesn't fit your original purpose.

Comment: @Jim But the "with construction is not parallel to the "is" construction on the front end. While not incorrect, it treats the eyes and hair differently from the other adjectives.

Comment: Another way to fix Edwin's concern is to lead off with smart: _I met a girl who is smart, tall, and beautiful, with big brown eyes and long black hair._ Or, you could say all this and so much more by saying, "I met a girl with a short skirt and a lonnnnng jacket." Piece of [CAKE](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/cake/shortskirtlongjacket.html). :^)

Comment: @J.R.- I like that one too.  (Your first one, I like the thought of the second one as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say:

> I met a girl who is smart, tall, and beautiful with big brown eyes and long black hair.

Adjective order could vary ...

Answer (score 3):

> I met a girl who is beautiful, smart, tall, [and]* has big brown eyes and
>   long black hair.

is how I would write it.

*optional